# How to decorate Image.file

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make a File image blurred and add radius in it.

**This is my code:**

```
BackdropFilter(
        filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
        child: new Container(
          width: width * 0.55,
          height: height * 0.70,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(

            //this is not accepted becuse Image.file is not ImageProvider
            image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new Image.file(new File(messageSnapshot.value['file'])),
                fit: BoxFit.cover
            ),

            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(10.0)),
          ),
          child: Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,)),
        ),
      )
```

How to achive this using Image.file widget?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Instead of `Image.File` widget use `FileImage` image provider

```
new DecorationImage(
  image: new FileImage(yourFile),
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Also just in case someone wants to use a Condition for the image this could work:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
    color: Colors.grey,
    image: DecorationImage(
    image: _image == null
    ? AssetImage('A_DEFAULT_IMAGE_PATH')
    : FileImage(YOUR_FILE),
    fit: BoxFit.cover
   ),
),
```